# Android create thread for pusher to run at background

Tags: android, multithreading

In my app, I am getting my messages instantly from my server via pusher. I have created a service designated to handle connections and firing broadcast messages to other activities in my app.

The problem that I face now is to have this service run in a new thread to have it still run even when my app goes to the background. I've found from [this](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-websocket-java/issues/33) that I should create and connect it to the "service thread", but I cannot find examples for it with pusher.

If anyone can, could you please provide an example to do so? If not, insights to writing code with these "service threads" would be helpful as well. Thanks in advance for the help :D

`PusherService.java`
    public class PusherService extends Service {

```
    private static final String TAG = "PusherService";

    private Pusher pusher = new Pusher("myKey");
    private Channel channel = pusher.subscribe("cafe_channel");

    private JSONObject pusherJSONObj;
    private Order order;

    public PusherService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //this service will run until we stop it
        setupPusher();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void setupPusher() {
        Log.d(TAG, System.currentTimeMillis()+"");
        channel.bind("customer_order", new SubscriptionEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(String channelName, String eventName, final String data) {
                Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();

                try {
                    pusherJSONObj = new JSONObject(data);
                    order = new Order(pusherJSONObj);

                    broadcastIntent.setAction("customer_order");
                    broadcastIntent.putExtra("message", "success");
                    broadcastIntent.putExtra("order", order);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("Pusher", "conversion failed");

                    broadcastIntent.setAction("customer_order");
                    broadcastIntent.putExtra("message", "JSON conversion error");
                }

                sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
            }
        });

        pusher.connect();
    }
}
```

`OrdersActivity.java`

```
private BroadcastReceiver pusherReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("customer_order")) {
            adapter.newOrder((Order) intent.getParcelableExtra("order"));
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that multithreading on one process does not solve my problem.

So instead, I split the service into a new process, which will keep the service running independent of the status of the main thread & process. Tested and found that service does not stall when my activities go background.